# Image cropping in php

Tags: php, crop

So I am trying to write a little script to crop a users image. I would send some information (width, height, alignment properties and image url) to the script and it should return the image cropped. However, it's not working... Just an "image not found" symbol :/ Here is my script, any thoughts?

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$w=$_GET['w'];
$h=$_GET['h'];
$x=$_GET['x'];
$y=$_GET['y'];
$filename="http://www.domain.com/".$_GET['src'];
$file_ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, ".") + 1);
$ext='';

if($file_ext=='jpg')
{
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
}
else if ($file_ext=='gif')
{
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename); 
}
else if ($file_ext=='png')
{
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); 
} 

$crop = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
imagecopy($crop, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h);
imagejpeg($crop);
?>
```

**Edit:** Looks like this is the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in domainpath/crop.php on line 24 Is there anything I need to do to load this function?

Comment: Watch the request/response in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), there's either whitespace or an error message in the response that you cannot see.

Comment: Drop the `Content-Type` header and hit that URL with a browser to see what the error is.  (Make sure error reporting is turned on.)

Comment: Looks like this is the error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in domainpath/crop.php on line 24

Is there anything I need to do to load this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)**, try this;

```
<?php
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    $img = new Imagick($file);
    if ($crop) {
        $img->cropThumbnailImage($w, $h);
    } else {
        $img->thumbnailImage($w, $h, TRUE);
    }

    return $img;
}
resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 150, 150);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment about the error, [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) is indeed a function, but only if you have the GD library loaded.

Make sure you have a compatible version of GD accessible to your PHP installation, and don't forget to restart your web server if you have just added it.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend u use imagemagick instead of GD / GD2 lib. If u looking for quality, imagemagick is too good for the same. There is this link which also gives compares on the same
http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/compair.php